# how to get alert when iframe video will stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

i have a video link that is in iframe i want to get alert when video will ended. i am doing something like this

```
var vid = document.getElementById("viddler-videoid");
vid.ended = function() {
   alert("code here");
};
```

```html
<iframe id="viddler-videoid" src="//www.viddler.com/embed/videoid/?f=1&autoplay=1&player=mini&make_responsive=0&hideFullScreenControl=true" width="497" height="375" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

can any one help me for this.

Update:
Actually i am facing browser problem with my old code. previously i am using this code showing below

```
<object width="497" height="375" id="viddlerOuter-videoId" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="//www.viddler.com/mini/videoid/"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="//www.viddler.com/mini/videoid/"> 
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                    <param name="flashVars" value="f=1&autoplay=t&hideablecontrolbar=1&enablecallbacks=t&disableseek=1&disablebranding=1&loop=0&nologo=1&hd=1&initialVolume=50">
                    <object id="viddlerInner-videoid"> 
                        <video id="viddlerVideo-videoid" src="//www.viddler.com/file/videoid/html5mobile?openURL=di" type="video/mp4" width="497" height="375" poster="//www.viddler.com/thumbnail/id/" controls="controls" x-webkit-airplay="allow"></video> 
                    </object>
                </object>
```

```html
function playEnded() {
    jwplayer('mediaspace').play();
}
```

this was working fine on firefox and chrome but now this code is running firefox only. in chrome browser video is not playing. that is why i update me video code with iframe. iframe video is running but 2nd video is not play which should be play after ended iframe video.

Comment: If you need this it would be much better to use a `video` element and hook to the events that raises.

Comment: well the iframe appears to be in a different domain so only way that would happen is if they send postMessages back to you that tells you what is going on.

Comment: If the iframe is on a different domain, then you can't do this unless the page on the iframe allows for it.

Comment: You'll need an upgraded membership to get the API keys http://developers.viddler.com/#introduction

Comment: @zer00ne yes i have account in viddler. but dot not know how to use its API. can you guide me how to handle it with API

Comment: @epascarello if i enable that postMessage then what will be the code of Javascript?